# Displaying Counter on The Actual HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a 'like' button; and underneath the button, I can display the 'like count'.

However, I want the 'like count' value to be displayed on the actual button itself. For example, I want the button to say: "Like 5"

How can I display both text and a variable value on a button?

Comment: can you please post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can improving with this code that i did.

HTML

```
<form id = "form" method = "POST">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Like" />
</form>

<br />

<div id = "clicks">
    counter = <label id = "count">0</label> clicks !
</div>
```

JS

```
function CountOnFormSubmitEvent(form_id, _callback_)
{
    var that = this, count = 0, callback = _callback_;

    var form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    if(form === null) { return null; }

    var reset = function(){
        count = 0;  
    };

    form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
        callback(evt, ++count, reset);
    }, false);
}

//Reseting Process You can delete if you dont want it.
var counter = new CountOnFormSubmitEvent("form", function(event, count, reset_callback){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(count >= 10)
    {
        alert("Reseting the process");
        reset_callback();
    }
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
});
```

Here is the link Jsfiddle.

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbksbrzg/1/)